# how to remove a input field after cloning in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

I am cloning a div with two input field where one is hidden field. Now I want to remove the hidden field from cloned div before append. I have no idea how to do it. I have goggled for it but no suitable code for my work or may be I am not understanding properly. Can anyone please help me on this please ?!!! Here are my code below ::

my div which I want to clone >>>

```
<div class="col-xs-4 wcmEdit" id="wcmEdit">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="participatedWcMemberName"><g:message code="so" default="Member Name" /></label>
                    <g:textField id="participatedWcMemberName${i}" name="participatedWcMemberName${i}" value="${wcMembers?.participatedWcMemberName}" class="form-control" required=""/>
                    <g:hiddenField name="participatedWcMemberId${i}" value="${wcMembers?.id}"/>
                    <a onclick="addAnotherWcMemberEdit()">Add More</a> ||
                    <a onclick="removeThisMember()">Remove</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

my function to clone the div >>>

```
function addAnotherWcMemberEdit(){
    var memberSign = 'participatedWcMemberName' + wcMemberCounterEdit
    $('#wcmEdit').clone().find('input').attr({
        value: '',
        id: memberSign, 
        name: memberSign
    }).end().appendTo('#wcMember');
    wcMemberCounterEdit++;
}
```

Comment: I just discovered these couple articles, and I think your custom elements are not recognized as true elements by the browser, which means that it is probably very hard or even impossible to remove the hidden field because it uses colon (g:hiddenField). So perhaps you need to rethink your approach to this issue. Useful links: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/?redirect_from_locale=ru and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.registerElement#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 6):

You can declare a variable and use it to hold the clone of your source inputs. Then .remove() the source inputs. Since you use .clone(), it creates deep clone so the variable will still hold the clones after the removal of the source. You can then variable.appendTo() or variable.prependTo().

Answer (score 1):

**2nd Update** I got your cloning working. However, jQuery `clone` method doesn't work as expected because the cloned div contains unconventional html elements/tags such as `<g:textField>` and `<g:hiddenField>`. Therefore after completion of `addAnotherWcMemberEdit` the cloned element looks like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-4 wcmEdit" id="wcmEdit_1">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="participatedWcMemberName">
        <g:message code="so" default="Member Name">
      </g:message></label>
      <g:textfield id="participatedWcMemberName1" name="participatedWcMemberName1" value="" class="form-control" required="">
          <g:hiddenfield name="participatedWcMemberId" value="wcMemberid">
              <a onclick="addAnotherWcMemberEdit()">Add More</a> ||
              <a onclick="removeThisMember()">Remove</a>
          </g:hiddenfield>
      </g:textfield>
   </div>
```

Following this strange cloning outcome, I was unable to remove the hidden element. For the user the end result doesn't look any different on the browser. I was also unable to remove the hidden element at its new location.

```js
var wcMemberCounterEdit = 1;

function addAnotherWcMemberEdit() {

  var memberSign = 'participatedWcMemberName' + wcMemberCounterEdit

  //clone
  $clonedDiv = $('#wcmEdit').clone();

  //new id for the cloned div, to make the id unique
  $clonedDiv.attr("id", "wcmEdit_" + wcMemberCounterEdit);

  //find textField (second child of class .form-group,
  //which I assume is your intended input)
  //and set attributes
  $clonedDiv.find('.form-group > :nth-child(2)').attr({
    value: '',
    id: memberSign,
    name: memberSign
  });

  //remove hidden field. This doesn't work (!) because the cloning
  // doesn't work as expected --> hidden field is not third element
  // following the cloning
  $clonedDiv.find('.form-group > :nth-child(3)').remove();

  //append cloned div
  $('#wcMember').append($clonedDiv);

  wcMemberCounterEdit++;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wcMember">
  <div class="col-xs-4 wcmEdit" id="wcmEdit">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="participatedWcMemberName">
        <g:message code="so" default="Member Name" />
      </label>
      <g:textField id="participatedWcMemberName${i}" name="participatedWcMemberName${i}" value="${wcMembers?.participatedWcMemberName}" class="form-control" required="" />
      <g:hiddenField name="participatedWcMemberId${i}" value="${wcMembers?.id}" />
      <a onclick="addAnotherWcMemberEdit()">Add More</a> ||
      <a onclick="removeThisMember()">Remove</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's then only add 2 , nothing else

Comment: @SumonBappi if there was fiddle I could test it (sorry my answer is currently not tested). Also, I would probably do those many method calls (clone, find + attr, eq, appendTo) in 4 separate steps because now there is a lot method chaining.

Comment: @SumonBappi I don't think you can remove the hidden element, at least by using jQuery because the cloning doesn't work as expected.

Comment: I think so but not sure.

Comment: @SumonBappi Btw, does the html in your question represent the serverside html code or is the html copy pasted from a browser during run time (for example in Chrome: More Tools -> Developer Tools -> Elements)? Anyway, instead of cloning those elements you could create your elements from scratch by using either document.createElement(..) or jQuery’s append method. However, I’m not sure whether those methods are going to work with g:textField element, probably not.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the [detach](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) method, which in a single function will remove an element from the dom and store it in a variable.

Usage:

```
  var storedElement = $('#my-element').detach();
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter your inputs by using this:http://api.jquery.com/filter/ and remove filtered with this: http://api.jquery.com/remove/